# How to find parameter of NonlinearModel?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fitting

My model is `g[x]=L[(x-d)*Cos[a]]`,but I don't know `L[x]`.I need to know `d` and `a`.When `x<0 or x>16`, `g[x]` will close to 0.

When `a=0` and `d=0` ,`g/@Range[1,16]` is:

```
t={5,5,8,10,13,17,2,-49,-85,-77,-22,15,17,13,9,7}
```

And some other data that I don't know `d` and `a` :

`{{5,5,8,10,13,17,5,-43,-84,-80,-28,13,17,13,9,7},{5,5,8,10,13,17,7,-37,-81,-83,-37,10,17,13,9,7},{5,5,7,10,12,17,10,-27,-77,-86,-51,3,17,14,10,8},{5,5,7,10,12,17,13,-17,-69,-87,-66,-10,15,15,11,9},{5,5,7,10,12,17,14,-11,-63,-86,-74,-24,11,16,12,10},{5,5,7,9,11,16,14,-3,-52,-86,-88,-56,-4,13,10,8}}`

I got those data from 16 sensors.

How to find `d` and `a` by those data?

---

Here are some code.
When `a=0` and `d=0` ,`g[x]=L[x]`.So `L = Interpolation[t]`.

```
L = Interpolation[t];
NonlinearModelFit[Thread[{Range[1,16],data}], L[(x - d)*Cos[a]], {a, d}, x]
```

It didn't work.How to fix this.

---

I tried another method.

```
L = Interpolation[t];
predict = 
  Table[Array[L[N@Cos[a]*(2 + # - d)] &, 12] -> {a*(180/Pi), d},
    {a, 0, Pi/6, Pi/180}, {d, -1, 1, 0.1}] // Flatten;
Nearest[predict, data[[;; , 3 ;; 14]]]
(*{{{1, 0.1}}, {{4, 0.2}}, {{12, 0.2}}, {{18, 
   0.2}}, {{25, -0.1}}, {{30, -0.2}}}*)
```

It looks work well.

Comment: Do you have `data = t`?

Comment: You could try finding `L` as a `NonlinearModelFit` for `t`, instead of an `InterpolatingFunction`. Your data looks a bit Mexican Hat to me, so you could start there. Then you'd have an explicit form to fit the rest of your data to.

Comment: @Coolwater No,data is one of test data.``{{...},...}``。

Comment: @aardvark2012 What's Mexican Hat?I'm not a native English speaker.And I don't know how to " finding L as a NonlinearModelFit for t".If I don't use `InterpolatingFunction`, how to get my function *form*?

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial answer in the sense that there are mathematical details that I have skipped over. I hope this can still give you a way forwards.

First, we need to get an explicit model to use in `NonlinearModelFit`. Your data looks to me like it could be fitted to *something like* the following:

```
model[x_] := c (((b - x)^2 - v^2)/(v^4)) Exp[-((x - b)^2/(2 v^2))]
```

This model will need lots of tweaking; maybe more parameters and a bit of persuasion in the constraints of `NonlinearModelFit`, or a different form entirely. The one I'm using is the second derivative of the Gaussian function. You might consider a difference of Gaussians or something entirely more exotic. Point is: this model isn't great, but you are probably in a better position to figure out a better one, and for me to go on about it would make this post a bit off-topic.

Anyway... Using your `t` data, we can get a fit for the parameters of `model`, and find `L`:

```
lfit = NonlinearModelFit[t, {model[x, b, c, v], c > 0}, {b, c, v}, x];
L = lfit["Function"];

Show[Plot[L[x], {x, 1, 16}], ListPlot[t], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

which is clearly not a very good fit, but it's as good as `model` can do. Now that we have an explicit form for L, we can use `NonlinearModelFit` as you intended:

```
fullfit = NonlinearModelFit[#, L[(x - d) Sin[a]], {a, d}, x] & /@ data;
params = Through[fullfit["BestFitParameters"]]

(* {{a -> 1.53048, d -> 0.0906855}, {a -> 1.41608, d -> 0.105093}, 
    {a -> 1.32928, d -> 0.139577}, {a -> 1.22656, d -> 0.0873524}, 
    {a -> 1.13135, d -> -0.113984}, {a -> 0.943693, d -> -0.901577}} *)
```

which gives the plots

```
GraphicsGrid[ArrayReshape[
  Table[Show[
    ListLinePlot[data[[i]]], Plot[L[(x - d) Sin[a]] /. params[[i]], {x, 1, 16}], 
  PlotRange -> All], {i, Length[data]}],
{2, 3}]]
```

[image]

These approximations clearly aren't great, but most of that is what they inherited from my original `model`. If you can obtain a decent form for `L`, with `a` and `d` zero, this approach should give you values for `a` and `d`.

Comment: You mean I must guess the expression of `L[x]`.It's hard to do so.

Comment: @erow It may take some trial and error, but I tried to give you some pointers and you will have insights from whatever process generated the data that I don't have. If you're struggling it might be an appropriate question for mathematicsSE (not mathoverflow), but I think it's a little off-topic here.

Comment: @erow Just to be clear, you only have to work out the _form_ of `L`. `NonlinearModelFit` will figure out the parameters. You might want to start by considering questions like: Is it going to asymptote to 0? Should it be periodic? How much confidence do you have that your data is right? ie, how good of a fit do you need it to be? These are all interesting questions, but not really specifically related to Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to expand on the fine answer provided by ***aardvark2012***.

### Part 1 - The zero model

The question is ***what is the best model for the d=0 and a=0 case?***

```
data = {
        {5, 5, 8, 10, 13, 17, 5, -43, -84, -80, -28, 13, 17, 13, 9, 7}, 
        {5, 5, 8, 10, 13, 17, 7, -37, -81, -83, -37, 10, 17, 13, 9, 7},
        {5, 5, 7, 10, 12, 17, 10, -27, -77, -86, -51, 3, 17, 14, 10, 8},
        {5, 5, 7, 10, 12, 17, 13, -17, -69, -87, -66, -10, 15, 15, 11, 9},
        {5, 5, 7, 10, 12, 17, 14, -11, -63, -86, -74, -24, 11, 16, 12, 10},
        {5, 5, 7, 9, 11, 16, 14, -3, -52, -86, -88, -56, -4, 13, 10, 8}
       }
```

The first row is the `d=0` and `a=0` data.

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data[[1]], PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.025], Red], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 16}, {-92, 22}}],
 ListLinePlot[data[[1]], PlotStyle -> Black]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I visualized this as the product of a sine wave with a Gaussian. The sin wave has a period of about 10. At `x=2` it is zero and again around `x=12`. The Gaussian is centered around 9 to 10.

When the Gaussian becomes tiny the data does not decay to zero but rather to a value of approximately 5.

Thus the `d=0` and `a=0` model that I visualize has the form:

```
amp Sin[2 π (x - x1)/period] Exp[-(x - x2)^2/taper] + offset
```

`x1` and `period` control where the sine function starts and its frequency, `x2` and `taper` controls the center of the exponential and how fast it declines.

`amp` is the overall amplitude and `offset` controls the asymptotic value as the exponential declines to zero.

```
L = NonlinearModelFit[data[[1]],  amp Sin[2 π (x - x1)/period] 
     Exp[-(x - x2)^2/taper] + offset,
     {{amp, 100}, {x1, 2}, {period, 10}, {x2, 10},
      {taper, 7.5}, {offset, 5}}, x]

L["BestFitParameters"]

(* {amp -> 97.3113, x1 -> 1.98992, period -> 9.81875, 
 x2 -> 9.43061, taper -> 7.47599, offset -> 6.63116} *)

L[x]
(* 6.63116 + 97.3113 E^(-0.133762 (-9.43061 + x)^2) Sin[0.639917 (-1.98992 + x)] *)

Show[
 ListPlot[data[[1]], PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.025], Red], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 16}, {-92, 22}}, ImageSize -> 400], 
 Plot[L[x], {x, 1, 16}, PlotStyle -> Black]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Part 2 - The non-zero model

We assume that `L` represents the zero model. Now the remaining data is fit to this model to determine the `d` and `a` values.

```
arrayL = NonlinearModelFit[data[[#]], 
    L[(x - d) Cos[a]], {{a, 0.01}, {d, 0.1}}, x] & /@ Range[6]

Through[arrayL["BestFitParameters"]]
(* {
    {a -> 7.60156*10^-6, d -> -1.13237*10^-10},
    {a -> 0.15871,  d -> 0.00228828},
    {a -> 0.248544, d -> 0.0226341},
    {a -> 0.346438, d -> -0.0248807},
    {a -> 0.435801, d -> -0.209244},
    {a -> 0.595756, d -> -0.798566}
   } *)

Grid@Partition[
  Table[
   Show[
    ListPlot[data[[i]], PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.03], Red], 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 16}, {-92, 22}}, ImageSize -> 200], 
    Plot[arrayL[[i]][x], {x, 1, 16}, PlotStyle -> Black]
    ],
   {i, Length[data]}], 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

***Warning***: In both cases I found the fits ***sensitive*** to the guess for the input parameters. The fits appear reasonable but that sensitivity is not a desirable property.

Comment: @erow See if this model for `L` meets your expectations.

Comment: Nicely done! Thanks for adding that.

Comment: @JackLaVigne It's Amazing.In fact, I get those data from magnetic sensors.The 16 inputs represent magnetic field.And `a` is the rotation angle of a magnetic stripe, `d` is the offset.Your answer is very close.``{{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {15, 0}, {20, 0}, {25, 0}, {30, 0}}`` is the exact answer.I will do more exercise.

Comment: I deleted one accidentally, And I don't know which one. You have good sense of math, the model is nice.